# Authorize Salesforce REST API without Username and password

Tags: api, rest, oauth, salesforce, clientid

I want to authorize(OAuth2) the Salesforce API from a service, using client_id, client_secret and redirect URL. I DO NOT want to keep username and password in my system. Can somebody please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement an OAuth flow, such as the [Web Server flow](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&type=5&id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_web_server_flow.htm) or [JWT bearer flow](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=5), both of which will allow you to  obtain new access tokens for the lifespan of your integration *without* storing raw user credentials. Note that you will still need a user account under which to authenticate.